# script to do maven install for my project in eclipse

Tags: java, maven

I want to run a  script to do a maven install for my project in eclipse since it takes more than an hour to download maven dependencies. I tried changing update policy to never in settings.xml .is it possible to perform maven install using the script and also I don't have maven installed  in my system

Comment: If I understand your question, you do not want to install, but you want to build the application using Maven ? Am I right ?

Comment: If you run `install` with Maven in Eclipse, it will not download all the dependencies (again) because they are already cached in your local repository. It will check updates on SNAPSHOT dependencies, this may take some time, but not more than one or two minutes. If it takes an hour, there is something very wrong going on.

Comment: some of the dependencies mentioned are not present.so they are not in my local repository